# For Group BY In SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql

Please Help Me For Select Query

**My Table Like**

```
| ID | Name | Salary | Month    |
|----|------|--------|----------|
| 1  | A    | 15000  | January  |
| 2  | B    | 20000  | January  |
| 3  | C    | 25000  | January  |
| 4  | A    | 14000  | February |
| 5  | B    | 19000  | February |
| 6  | c    | 24000  | February |
| 7  | A    | 16000  | March    |
| 8  | B    | 21000  | March    |
| 9  | C    | 26000  | March    |
```

**I wanna Result Like**

```
| Name | January | February | March |
|------|---------|----------|-------|
| A    | 15000   | 14000    | 16000 |
| B    | 20000   | 19000    | 21000 |
| C    | 25000   | 24000    | 26000 |
```

Comment: Please show your effort on this. What you have did yet for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create temporary table `tab`
(ID int, Name varchar(10), Salary int, Month varchar(30));


insert into `tab` (ID ,Name, Salary ,Month)   -- insert all statement
values(9, 'C' ,26000 ,'March');

select  *from tab;

select 
name,
sum(case when month = 'January'  then salary else null end) as January
,sum(case when month = 'February'  then salary else null end) as February
,sum(case when month = 'March'  then salary else null end) as March
from tab
group by name;
```

output

```
name, January, February, March
A,    15000,   14000,    16000
B,    20000,   19000,    21000
C,    25000,   24000,    26000
```

Comment: it means you have to provide 12 case statements for 12 months